# Door, space separator options with limited frame space?

Tags: doors, door-frame, design

I want to separate a big room into a working room and open kitchen space.

[image]

The problem in separating the space is to find proper door -- the problem is that it is very hard to get a door frame to a frame of window and balcony door:

[image]

The window-door frame is about 7-9cm and limited by the valve of water-based heater.

Consider also this option where finding door mechanisms would be even more important:

[image]

where you may want to use consistent style and mechanisms in both doors, not two separate door designs like the picture.

**What are options to separate a space with limited frame space?**

Comment: It is unclear to me where the  door will be located ( in the space on the right? ) and what the space construction is or what other limitation are in the space I.E.other things such as windows, heaters and there distance from the proposed door etc.

Comment: Agreed that it's difficult to know exactly what you're after from your description. I presume you want to separate the smaller "MH" from "OH" and that your initial plan is that the door would be along the wall dividing them from "PARVEKE"? Your last drawing shows what might be a sliding barn-door near the other end of the "MH"/"OH" wall as a secondary option? If any of this assumption is accurate, please [edit] your post to indicate that. If not, please indicate what, very specifically, you are after. Otherwise, the best you'll get is a list of different types of doors.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I highlighted the door with framing problem with limited space and the next picture is trying to pinpoint that closer. Third photo shows that adding more doors may make the problem even harder and trying to find consistent style is not easy. It it now clearer?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Labelled the bedrooms with MH1 and MH2.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still not 100% clear, however, I can think of 3 options:

- Make both doors pocket doors.

  - These slide *into* the wall and are, therefore, quite narrow. Where the door butts up against the "PARVEKE" wall, it would only be 1" - 1 1/2" wide (~25-37 mm) and should fit against the trim between the existing window and door in that wall.
  - You would, in effect, be using the "PARVEKE" wall as the right side of the door's frame instead of using that part of the frame. This would take some careful work to ensure that the door's top track/frame is accurately attached to that wall so the door can slide properly.
  - The door would open into the wall to the left (from the point of view of the drawing) and close to the right against the window/door trim.
  - You might need to adjust/replace the existing trim so that it's a flat surface for the door to close against if you need a good, tight closure. i.e. if you have some sort of curved surfaces on the trim now, the door may not fit well against it.
  - A matching pocket-door (opening whichever direction is most convenient/aesthetically pleasing) at the other location is an easy install.
- Make both doors barn doors.

  - Barn doors slide along the wall (instead of inside the wall like a pocket door) and don't swing. They take up minimal floor space.
  - It's possible that the door that meets the "PARVEKE" wall will butt up against the trim (you'd want it to be on the window side, not the door side) and that may not be optimal, but you would still be able to operate the window.
  - Install a matching door at the other location.
- Offset the "PARVEKE" wall door further to the left.

  - This will take the most work.
  - Build a short stub wall dividing "MH" and "OH" and have this meet the "PARVEKE" wall, *replacing* the trim between them with a wall at a 90° angle.
  - You now have the exact same wall condition for this door as you do for the one to the left and you can use any door you choose in any width you desire without worrying about running into the trim between window and door (since that trim no longer exists).

#### A fourth option:

Drop the door at the "PARVEKE" wall and go with *only* the door on the left.

Comment: I try to visualise your options 3 and 4 here https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/197576/4605 I think maybe option 4 is better because the other window at the about the same level as the door.

Answer (score 1):

This answer summarizes all potential options:

1. pivot door
2. sliding door
3. internal door with thin/slim physical dimensions particularly for the frame
4. curtain
5. some Japanese door design
6. pocket door
7. Hanging bead curtain
8. Accordion folding wall/door (very common for dividing large spaces)
9. ...

Answer (score 1):

### Option 4

Answer [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/197544/4605) and its fourth option visualisation with DreamPlan software:

There has to be 1.3 metre circular working space in front of the kitchen:

[image]

[image]

View from the main door:

[image]

### Option 3

Versus its third option with OFFSET.
There has to be 1.3 metre circular working space in front of the kitchen:

[image]

[image]

View from the main door:

[image]

### Discussion

I think the option 4 could be the best one here because the door and MH2 window are at the same line, also easier to build that door than in option 3. Also in option 4, the door is closer to the main door so the shorter distance from the main door to MH2, which is a good thing.

### Visualisation

DreamPlan: 5.28.
OS: OS X Catalina 10.15.5.
Sofas 2-seat: Ikea Klippan code 790.106.14, width: 91 cm height: 37 cm length: 182 cm.
Other sizes standard from DreamPlan.